# How to split second column by ';' and append first column value

Tags: bash, awk, split, text-processing, data-processing

What is the best and the simplest way to do it?

I have tsv file with two columns:

```
id1<\tab>name1;name2;name3
id2<\tab>name11;name22;name3
id3<\tab>name111;name2;name3333
```

I want to change columns order ((names)<\tab>id), split first column by ';' and append corresponding id to each row. I mean something like that:

```
name1<\tab>id1
name2<\tab>id1
name3<\tab>id1
name11<\tab>id2
name22<\tab>id2
name3<\tab>id2
name111<\tab>id3
name2<\tab>id3
name3333<\tab>id3
```

Thank You for help!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO(not my downvote btw), thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box, one option would be to set the field separator to include both the tab character, and the semicolon.

```sh
awk -F'[\t;]' -v OFS='\t' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $i, $1}' file
```

Sample run:

```sh
$ cat -A file
id1^Iname1;name2;name3$
id2^Iname11;name22;name3$
id3^Iname111;name2;name3333$
```

```sh
$ awk -F'[\t;]' -v OFS='\t' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $i, $1}' file | cat -A
name1^Iid1$
name2^Iid1$
name3^Iid1$
name11^Iid2$
name22^Iid2$
name3^Iid2$
name111^Iid3$
name2^Iid3$
name3333^Iid3$
```

Comment: Names first, then ID. Switch the order. (Point is still valid, though.)

Comment: @EdMorton: Thanks for the edit, yes indeed it looks like I confused the restriction in `RS` with the `FS`. Good point about the space too.

Answer (score 1):

In the bash interpreter -

```
 while IFS="$IFS;" read -a c;do for n in 1 2 3; do echo "${c[$n]}   ${c[0]}"; done<file
```

or

```
while IFS="$IFS;" read id n1 n2 n3; do printf "%s\t%s\n" $n1 $id $n2 $id $n3 $id; done<file
```

I *could* have said `printf "%s\t$id\n" $n1 $n2 $n3` but it's usually a bad idea to embed a variable into a format string...